# Flutter call function from other class?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am building flutter function which able to capture qr code and after display the result after user scan QR Code. I need user to be able  navigate to previous scanning screen by using button if they need rescan or scan new qr code. This is code for button which on **Scanview** class.

```
 SizedBox(height: 40,),
          CupertinoButton(
              color: Color(0xFF88070B),
              child:Text("Re-scan QR "),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => **ScanFunction**(),
                  ),
                );
              }
          )
```

I want to call this **_scanQR** method from other class **ScanFunction** . What is proper way when user tap **Re-scan QR** button and call _scanQR method which is on other class? How to access method from other class? Thanks for help.

```
class ScanFunction extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ScanFunctionState createState() {
    return ScanFunctionState();
  }
}

class ScanFunctionState extends State<ScanFunction>  {

  String result = "Maklumat Inventori";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();

      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scanresultview(qrResult),
        ),
      );
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Kebenaran kamera telah ditolak";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Ralat tidak diketahui$ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "Anda menekan butang belakang sebelum mengimbas apa-apa";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Ralat tidak diketahui $ex";
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method from `initState`.

```
class ScanFunction extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ScanFunctionState createState() {
    return ScanFunctionState();
  }
}

class ScanFunctionState extends State<ScanFunction>  {

  @override
  void initState() {
     _scanQR();
     super.initState();
  }

  String result = "Maklumat Inventori";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();

      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Scanresultview(qrResult),
        ),
      );
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Kebenaran kamera telah ditolak";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Ralat tidak diketahui$ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "Anda menekan butang belakang sebelum mengimbas apa-apa";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Ralat tidak diketahui $ex";
      });
    }
  }
```